# How find optimal entry/exit thresholds for a mean-reverting process?

Tags: quant-trading-strategies, mean-reversion

Suppose we have $\{X_{t}\}$ mean-reverting process. The goal is to find optimal entry and exit thresholds which can maximize P&L of the trading strategy. I have 2 "empirical" approaches off the top of my head:

1. Find out entry and exit thresholds based on historical $\{X_{t}\}$ series. In other words, retrospectively, find values for thresholds which could maximize P&L, if applied.
2. Fit AR(1) model on $\{X_{t}\}$ data, estimate parameters and simulate $N$ paths of the stochastic process. Then apply the approach described above (1) to these paths. Select thresholds which most often maximize P&L.

Are 1) and 2) reasonable? Which method could be better? Also, are there alternative approaches? I am aware of solutions within analytical framework (e.g., [Leung and Li, 2015](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.5062.pdf)), but I am interested in empirical/simulation approaches.

Comment: Take a look at these two articles: Bertram, William K. "Optimal trading strategies for Itô diffusion processes." Physica A: Statistical Mechanics and its Applications 388.14 (2009): 2865-2873. Bertram, William K. "Analytic solutions for optimal statistical arbitrage trading." Physica A: Statistical mechanics and its applications 389.11 (2010): 2234-2243.

Comment: Thank you, will have a look. Though I read the second one.